# Single Database Replication on OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

Good Day. I have recently installed OrientDB and tested the replication, I would just like to know if this is possible to replicate only a single database or set in config on which databases that needs to be replicated if you have multiple databases and do not wish to replicate all of them.

I don't know if this question has been answered yet, I haven't found a answer on the net that can tell me this.

Hope that someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, with replicate a single database, do you mean copy the database, for example in another version of OrientDB?

Comment: Hi, no not a another version. Say to have 3 databases 1 prod database with all client info and details and 2 test databases, and you have copied only the prod databases over to the second node. When I start the replication, I don't want all 3 to replicate to the second node, only the prod database.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replicate the database, for example in another version of OrientDB you have differents way:

1) export/import the DB;

2) copy and paste the folder into the databases's folder of the new version.

Otherwise, if you want to replicate the database, OrientDB supports Multi Master Replication. This means that all the nodes in the cluster are Master and are able to read and write to the database. Replication works only in the Distributed-Architecture. For more information about this type of replication please take a look on this: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Replication.html

Hope it hepls.

Comment: Thanks for that but have the same version of OrientDB on both of the nodes, If I have 3 databases on the 1 node, I only want 1 of the databases to replicate to the second node not all 3.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the folder that contains the DB into the others folders?

Comment: Yes I have, it not working all my databases is still replicating even my test databases as well, can't I just set which databases need to be replicated in the config?